# Rebasing a long-lived Subversion branch

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, branch, rebase

I have a large SVN repository (~40k revisions), in which a particular feature branch was created a very long time ago (ca. 15k) for the then-current version of the product.  However other things took priority and it was pushed back a few releases, until now.

Over time the branch was kept up to date with merges from trunk and other sub-branches, and it still builds and runs fine in its current state.

However trying to `switch` between this branch and trunk results in a lot of delete-readd actions (presumably because since the common branch point, the files were added to trunk and then the adds were merged to the feature branch, so now they're seen as replacements rather than modifications).  While this is not directly harmful in itself in a clean tree, it does waste time and network traffic and causes major conflicts instead of quiet merges if switching with a dirty tree.

Consequently, I'd like to rebase this branch by deleting it, creating a fresh new branch from the current trunk, and then merging in all the "real" changes from the previous branch.  (The idea being that this will simplify future switches, and make it easier to see what the real changes are.)

Most advice I can find on the subject says simply to `merge old-feature-branch` and let the merge tracking take care of the rest.  However I've tried that (via TSVN's Test Merge button only, so far) a few times and with a few smaller subsets of revisions but inevitably I seem to get massive conflicts on all sorts of files that should never have been touched by old-feature-branch in the first place.

When I try it with a real merge (from a working copy in new-feature-branch, `svn merge svn://url/branches/old-feature-branch`), I get this error:

```
svn: E160013: File not found: revision 38143, path '/branches/new-feature-branch'
```

Which, ok, sure, the new feature branch wasn't created until 38509, so it doesn't exist then.  But I don't know why it seems to think it might.  That particular revision was nothing fancy, just a small change to trunk that should already be in new-feature-branch's history and therefore not merged anyway.

Is there a tool or procedure that I can follow that simplifies this, or do I just have to work my way through all the revisions and conflicts manually?  I'm ok with "squashing" the history into either a single commit or a smaller series of commits than were originally made to the branch.

Comment: One other idea I had was to merge trunk into old-feature-branch, create new-feature-branch, and then merge old-feature-branch into new-feature-branch.  This seems like it should have worked but it still produced a lot of erroneous "replaced" files, which was part of the problem I was trying to solve by rebasing in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "Merge Hell" for merging `old-feature-branch` into `trunk` and `old-feature-branch` into `new-feature-branch` will **not** differ greatly - both merges will start from the same (very old) branchpoint, new-feature-branch path will be even 1 revision longer
2. For SVN 1.6+ (but  I'll suggest 1.8+ with really easier and smarter /than 1.6/ merge) you can *try* (but do not expect the miracle in any case) merge using *both operative and peg-revision* in merge source (using HEAD of `old-feature-branch`)
3. For any of giant merges you can get list of unmerged revisions between trees `svn mergeinfo --show-revs eligible ...` and merge in step-by-step style (`svn merge -c` - less disasters on each merge)
4. If branch-history (for `old-feature-branch`) isn't important and not needed in `new-feature-branch` you can just replace content in new branch

   - Export HEAD of `old-feature-branch` into $SOMETHING
   - Create `new-feature-branch` from trunk's HEAD and checkout it
   - Replace fully content of `new-feature-branch` WC with $SOMETHING
   - Commit this "squashed" history of changes as new revision of `new-feature-branch`
   - Forget for every-day tasks about `old-feature-branch`

Comment: I think an important step missing from this procedure is to first merge the HEAD of trunk (or more correctly, whichever revision `new-feature-branch` is created from) into `old-feature-branch`.  Otherwise the contents of `new-feature-branch` won't properly represent "trunk plus the changes in old-feature-branch".

Comment: Having said that, I've tried this (because I got sick of resolving the same conflicts repeatedly in a bottom-up merge) and it looks mostly good.  There are still a few more things in the diff against trunk than there should have been, but I don't think this is a fault in this procedure, I think this is just a sign that prior merges have gone awry and the branch was in worse shape than I had thought.